# TestNG : unknown option '-serport'

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

I am using TestNG with Eclipse Keplar. I followed exact steps provided [here](http://selftechy.com/2012/01/09/setting-up-testng-with-eclipse) for installing TestNG plugin for Eclipse. Installation was successful.

When I try to run TestNG testsuite, I am getting error as

```
[testng] Unknown option: -serport'
```

How do I remove this option from Eclipse's `Run As TestNG test` menu or edit configuration file of Eclipse to remove this option from `Run as TestNG test` ?

Stacktrace

```
 Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.ParameterException: Unknown option: -serport
    at com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parseValues(JCommander.java:742)
```

Comment: Keplar is a bit too old. TestNG no more supports it even if the documentation wasn't updated since a long time. Why do you not update your eclipse?

Comment: Ok, let me try with latest Eclipse.

Comment: @juherr, No, even with Eclipse Mars, I am getting same error.

Answer (score 6):

I got this working by doing the following:
In eclipse --> Project --> Properties --> TestNG
Uncheck the checkbox "Use Project TestNG jar"